# Replacing e method in preg replace callback that contains arrays

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm not great at writing expressions. I'm trying to solve the following PHP error:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback

There's been other questions on here that deal with the same issue however my expression contains arrays and I need to make sure I'm writing this correctly and in an efficient way. The deprecated code was written as follows:

```
public static function camelize($property)
{
    return preg_replace(array('/(^|_| )+(.)/e', '/\.(.)/e'), array("strtoupper('\\2')", "'_'.strtoupper('\\1')"), $property);
}
```

I've replaced it with the following:

```
    public static function camelize($property)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(array('/(^|_| )+(.)/', '/\.(.)/'), array(create_function ('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[2]);'), create_function ('$match', 'return strtoupper($match[1]);')), $property);
}
```

Is this going to cause any errors?

Comment: "***Is this going to cause any errors?***"  Do you see any errors on your log ?

Comment: I'm more looking for someone to tell me if the code is valid and the most efficient way of running the code before I run it.